# iPhone is not available. Please reconnect the device. / iOS 14.2 - Xcode 12.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swiftui

I just updated my iPhone to iOS 14.2.

When I want to launch an app on the device from Xcode, I now keep seeing this:

[image]

I also just updated Xcode to Version 12.1, hoping it would solve the problem, but it doesn't make any difference, I keep getting the same message.

I tried disconnecting and reconnecting the device, but to no avail.

I also removed all the data under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/, but again with no effect.

It seems like some other people have had this issue before, but I didn't find any working solution for me.

I hope someone with a recent similar experience can point me in the right direction for a proper way to solve this problem.

Comment: I see you have two good answers. I learned yesterday that there's a difference between "Gold Master" or GM and "Release Candidate" or... Beta 4. :-( I'm guessing this week Apple will straighten things out - this is two years in a row that they've bungled version releases, but in two days their "One More Thing" (ARM Macs) will likely sort things out, including Xcode. Until then, you can always use 12.2 Beta 4 alongside whichever production version of Xcode with no issue. (I wanted to skip 12.1 because I'm focused on iPadOS.)

Comment: It's weird that, I reconnected the device and reconnected the internet to my Mac, It started working afterwords.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

- Go to my Github repo [iOS 14.2 Device Support File](https://github.com/seyitcodeit/14.2.git) and download 14.2.zip file directly and after unzip it
- And just copy and paste unzipped folder by path:

  ```
  Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
  ```
- Restart the Xcode

That's all. You can build and go on your project.

If you need a visual solution, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64854525

---

***Why we have done these steps?***: Because Xcode 12.1 doesn’t include support for 14.2 so we implemented its device support files for 14.2.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_1-release-notes

---

Comment: I installed the 14.2 files in the folders and rebooted, but it still doesn't work (macOS 10.15.7). Is there something else I can try?

Comment: No need for a macOS reboot, but I did have to disconnect and then reconnect my device before this worked.

Comment: This seems to be the accepted answer for all these questions, but I think there is something bigger going on. I have the latest xcode version with the matching device support files for my device, and it still does not work for me. I've tried restarting, cleaning, deleting all saved device information, etc. and still get this error.

Comment: thanks for feedbacks fellows. please note that this is device support files for 14.2 and adding the true path. happy coding

Comment: This solution worked for me on Xcode 12.0, thank you. But why things have to be so tricky with *every* update from Apple?

Comment: This did not work for me on xcode 12.1, ios 14.1

Comment: @Zenman this is for 14.2 not 14.1 as i indicated

Comment: The way I resolved this in the end, keeping xcode version 12.1 with ios version 14.1 was to reset my iPhone. I was getting the message "failed to prepare device for development" in the 'devices and simulators' section. Resetting the iPhone resolved this.

Comment: @ZenmanC at least it is working , happy to hear now :)

Answer (score 8):

**Update**: Xcode 12.2, with support for iOS 14.2, is now available on the AppStore. If you find this problem with a newer version of iOS and Xcode, the answer is still the same, you can (probably) download the beta for the next Xcode version from the Apple Developer website, you can wait for the AppStore version to be updated, or you can (probably) find the symbols for the new iOS version and copy them to your current Xcode installation.

**Original answer. Applies to Xcode 12.1 and iOS 14.2**

The latest version of Xcode in the AppStore doesn’t include support for 14.2. You can download a beta of the next version from the Apple Developer website that supports 14.2, or wait for the AppStore version to be updated.

Comment: OK. Thanks. If that is the case. I wish I had been aware of that before and I would have waited to update my iOS.

Comment: It's always a good idea to hold off on iOS updates on your development devices because this kind of thing happens all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Per the official post from Apple, devices running iOS 14.2 are only supported in Xcode 12.2 RC. (source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_2-release-notes)

You can download beta versions of Xcode via: https://developer.apple.com/download/