# Error while running xcode 11.3.1 with ios 14.1 real device

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using  xcode 11.3.1  with ios 14.1 real device the compiler gave me below message.
the project restricted to use xcode 11.3.1 , i have installed 14.1 ios support file to xcode package content.

```
An error was encountered while attempting to communicate with this device. (The service is invalid.)
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402653150
Failure Reason: Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000022).
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a5416e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a541de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a552d0c __63-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startFirstServiceOf:unlockKeybag:]_block_invoke + 301
```

Comment: Xcode 11.3.1 won't work with an iOS device "out of the box". Xcode 12.1 will. I haven't tried this - and you will have issue with iOS 14 only APIs, but you should be able to download the support files needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736953/iphone-is-not-available-please-reconnect-the-device-ios-14-2-xcode-12-1

Comment: I have added support file  , but still got an above error

Comment: Then I can only think of two options - upgrade to Xcode 12.1 or use the simulator. (The simulator doesn't work for me because my apps involve CoreImage.) Wish I could offer more help.