# Why Xcode 12.2 (12B45b) is showing "iPhone is not available" for iOS 14.1?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Worked on my project last night but today Xcode is showing this today. Any idea how to solve that?

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned my iPhone's iOS version is 14.1

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736953/iphone-is-not-available-please-reconnect-the-device-ios-14-2-xcode-12-1) thread. It gives details on how to fix this issue. If all fails, try restarting your mac and device, check signing and Capabilities in the project